# Why does amplifier power efficiency not consider the power input by the input signal?

Tags: voltage, power, transistors, circuit-analysis, current

If we are considering efficiency of a power amplifier, shouldn't I consider all sources of input and output power? Therefore, why doesn't efficiency consider the power of the input signal as follows:

$$\frac{Average \space Power \space of \space Output \space Signal}{Average \space Power\space of\space DC \space Supply\space + \space Average\space Power\space of \space Input \space Signal}$$

As opposed to:

$$\frac{Average \space Power \space of \space Output \space Signal}{Average \space Power\space of\space DC \space Supply\space}$$

Comment: In many cases, the input power is negligible.

Comment: Also, by convention.

Comment: But, in the RF world, the metric called Power Added Efficiency, or PAE, does take into account the input power.  PAE = (Pout-Pin)/Pdc.  This is similar to what OP showed, except that Pin is subtracted from the numerator, rather than being added to the denominator.

Comment: @Andyaka A power amplifier is a large-signal amplifier, so shouldn't the power of the input signal be considered?

Comment: Where did you get this formula Pout/Supply from?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stack exchange Cojoye!

In a power amplifier, the flow of current is primarily from the supply to the output. So from this perspective, it might be easier to think of the supply as the "input power" and the output as the "output power".

In regards to the input signal, we should keep in mind that the input impedance to a good amplifier will be extremely large. So large that the current being drawn from the upstream input signal is negligible. No current means no power! Therefore it is usually not considered. The input should be considered as just a control signal carrying information, not a source of power.

Let me know if anything is unclear!

Comment: The exception is high frequency RF amps which often have fairly low power gain (10dB or less is not uncommon in higher microwave bands) where the metric "Power Added Efficiency" is often used (Pout - Pin)/Pdc, which is pretty much what you are asking for. Most other amplifiers have way more then 20dB of power gain, at which point the difference is less then 1%, so who cares.

Answer (score 0):

> If we are considering efficiency of a power amplifier, shouldn't I consider all sources of input and output power?

I don't think so. Usually the input signal is used to *control* or *modulate* the output and the input signal doesn't make it as far as the output.

I'm trying to think of an analogy and two automobile related ones do come to mind:

- Engine power control. I doubt that anyone would include the effort of depressing the accelerator pedal into account when working out the efficiency of the engine. Why? Because the effort doesn't contribute to the motion.
- On the other hand, the power-steering is a little different as the turning effort does contribute to the steering and the "power" part is an assistance to the manual input which still works when the engine is off.

In the case of the typical amplifier you will get no output if the amplifier power is removed so it is more like the accelerator example.